# how can I change info_link to red colour and increase font size after clicking on it?

Tags: javascript, html, css

```html
<div class="sidebar_links">
    <h3 id="info_link">Info</h3>
    <h3 id="qualification_link">Qualification</h3>
    <h3 id="download_link">Download CV</h3>
</div>
```

how can I change info_link to red colour and increase font size after clicking on it using javascript function like addEventlistener() or any?

Answer (score 0):

You can do something like this:

```
var link = document.getElementById("info_link");
link.onclick = function () {
    link.classList.toggle("clicked");
}
```

With the CSS class:

```
.clicked {
    color: red;
    font-size: 25px;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Use event listeners and JavaScript.

```js
document.getElementById('info_link').addEventListener('click', function() {
  document.getElementById('info_link').style.color = 'red';
});
```

```html
<div class="sidebar_links">
  <h3 id="info_link">Info</h3>
  <h3 id="qualification_link">Qualification</h3>
  <h3 id="download_link">Download CV</h3>
</div>
```